# Modeling market growth, without compound interest or regression

Tags: economic-growth

I am working on predicting the growth of a certain market. Traditionally, this is done through a simple compound interest model:

$$ ThisYear'sMarket * (1 + g)^n $$

What would be a better way to mimic progressive growth in real life? Perhaps through a natural log function or some form of $ y = e^x $? (There isn't enough past data so I'm not comfortable using regression).

Comment: Isn't $y = e^x$ exactly the same type of compound interest model...? (it is hard to tell because you do not specify what $x$ is, but I am guessing it is the same as $n$)

Comment: How are you wanting to parameterize the growth function though? You’ll have to use some sort of data if what you wish to do is forecast (unless theres other methods?)

Comment: I meant $ x $ as in $f(x) = e^x$. The input would one years worth of consumption from each sector. As an example, let's say there is 30,000 tons consumption of chemical x and 40,000 tons of chemical y. Market for for chemical x is expected to grow at 5%, while y is expected to grow at 4%.

Comment: There is 2 more years worth of consumption numbers that can be use to sort of validate the model's result. And yes I had a feeling $y = e^x$ might be the same type of compound interest model, hence my doubt if $y = e^x$ will be a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: $$\text{This Year's Market} \times (1 + g)^n = \text{This Year's Market} \times e^{n \log_e(1+g)}$$

Comment: @Henry this is super helpful

Comment: Surely the model should depend on the type of market?  If it's a market for a new good which many people want one of but few will want more than one (eg a new kind of device, perhaps), then after an initial growth phase it will eventually become saturated and predictions based on exponential or similar models will become very misleading, In that case it could be helpful to model ownership of the good as a  [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) and market demand as growth in ownership, plus something for replacement.

Comment: @AdamBailey agreed. Of course, my question is just one component to a larger model. What would be your suggestion to model this mathematically? Perhaps some variant of the sigmoid function, $f(x) = \frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$  ? How would you adjust the function so that market growth is capped at a reasonable threshold?